# Displaying current date with Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";
var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
document.write(n + getDate + getFullYear);
```

I'm having trouble displaying the current date. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: `getDate` and `getFullYear` need to be accessed through the _Date instance_, `d`, and they are _functions_ so they need to be _invoked_ with `()`, i.e. `d.getDate()`. Also, don't forget about _Array literals_ `['a', 'b', 'c']`, they will save you a lot of typing.

Comment: As it stands, the current code will most likely throw a _ReferenceError_. You can see any error messages in your browser's _Console_ (usually accessible by F12 or Ctrl+Shift+J). The message will give you some useful hints about what may be wrong and the line number (clicking the line number will take you to exactly where the error was thrown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in your call to document.write. You need to call getDate and getFullYear on the date object you created (d). See below

```js
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";
var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
document.write(n + ', ' + d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear());
```